# How to read multiple types of Avro data in single MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloud, avro

**I have two different types of Avro data which have some common fields. I want to read those common fields in the mapper. I want to read this by spawning a single job in cluster.**

*Below is the sample avro schema*

Schema 1:

> {"type":"record","name":"Test","namespace":"com.abc.schema.SchemaOne","doc":"Avro storing with schema using MR.","fields":[{"name":"EE","type":"string","default":null},
>   {"name":"AA","type":["null","long"],"default":null},
>   {"name":"BB","type":["null","string"],"default":null},
>   {"name":"CC","type":["null","string"],"default":null}]}

Schema 2 :

> {"type":"record","name":"Test","namespace":"com.abc.schema.SchemaTwo","doc":"Avro
>   storing with schema using
>   MR.","fields":[{"name":"EE","type":"string","default":null},
>   {"name":"AA","type":["null","long"],"default":null},
>   {"name":"CC","type":["null","string"],"default":null},
>   {"name":"DD","type":["null","string"],"default":null}]}

Driver Class:

```
package com.mango.schema.aggrDaily;

import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroJob;
import org.apache.avro.mapred.Pair;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RunningJob;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class AvroDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JobConf conf = new JobConf(super.getConf(), getClass());
        conf.setJobName("DF");

        args[0] = "hdfs://localhost:9999/home/hadoop/work/alok/aggrDaily/data/avro512MB/part-m-00000.avro";
        args[1] = "/home/hadoop/work/alok/tmp"; // temp location
        args[2] = "hdfs://localhost:9999/home/hadoop/work/alok/tmp/10";

        FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(conf, args[0]);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[2]));

        AvroJob.setInputReflect(conf);
        AvroJob.setMapperClass(conf, AvroMapper.class);

        AvroJob.setOutputSchema(
                conf,
                Pair.getPairSchema(Schema.create(Schema.Type.STRING),
                        Schema.create(Schema.Type.INT)));

        RunningJob job = JobClient.runJob(conf);

        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long startTime = new Date().getTime();
        System.out.println("Start Time :::::" + startTime);
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(conf, new AvroDriver(), args);
        long endTime = new Date().getTime();
        System.out.println("End Time :::::" + endTime);
        System.out.println("Total Time Taken:::"
                + new Double((endTime - startTime) * 0.001) + "Sec.");
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

Mapper class:

```
package com.mango.schema.aggrDaily;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
import org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroCollector;
import org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroMapper;
import org.apache.avro.mapred.Pair;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class AvroMapper extends
        AvroMapper<GenericData, Pair<CharSequence, Integer>> {

    @Override
    public void map(GenericData record,
        AvroCollector<Pair<CharSequence, Integer>> collector, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("record :: " + record);
    }

}
```

*I able to read Avro data with this code by setting the input schema.*

`AvroJob.setInputSchema(conf, new AggrDaily().getSchema());`

As the Avro data has builtin schema into the data, I don't want to pass the specific schema to the job explicitly. I achieve this in Pig. But now I want to achieve the same in MapReduce also.

Can anybody help me to achieve this through MR code or let me know where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By  *org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.**MultipleInputs** class we can read multiple avro data trough single MR job

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs to read multiple avro data because each one of the avro inputs will have a schema associated with it and currently context can store the schema for only one of the inputs. So other mappers will not be able read data..

The same thing is true with HCatInputFormat as well (because every input has a schema associated with it). However in Hcatalog 0.14 onwards there is a provision for the same.

AvroMultipleInputs can be used to accomplish the same. It works only with Specific and Reflect mappings. It is available from version 1.7.7 onwards.